# How can I use the FLASH key of my IP phone to transfer a call (atxfer)

Tags: asterisk, sip

My IP phone has a FLASH key. This key sends the DTMF of Flash [16 in decimal] (http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/SIP+DTMF+Signalling).

How do I set the atxfer parameter in the features.conf?